# How can I remove rows that have duplicate cells in 2 dif files - while choosing which file has the dup removed?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, file-geodatabase, duplication

I have 2 files and I merged them together into one file-geodatabase feature class. I want to remove entries from File1, Column C, that also appear in File2, ColumnD. I attempted to use the geoprocessing tool DeleteIdentical but it deletes from EITHER File1 or File2 (aka Column C or Column D). I need to specify that only rows from File1 (Column C) should be deleted. I can distinguish in the merged File1_2_Merge which column belongs to which file. I am using ArcGIS 10.2 Desktop. All 3 files are file-geodatabase feature classes.

Comment: I don't believe there is a builtin tool to do this. I would go the route of using a search cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would eliminate the duplication before the merge, then address this in a couple of steps.

1. **Join** File2 to File1 (Right-click File1 in the table of contents, choose **Joins and Relates/ Join**, **Join attributes from a table**. Base the join on **Column C**. The table to join to this layer will be **File2**, and the field to base the join on will be **Column D**. Choose **Keep all records**. This will retain File1 as-is but also include a new column to represent File2.)
2. **Select** features from File1 where Column D is not null (these will be the rows where Column C and Column D match, so, your duplicate rows).
3. **Delete** your selection from File1.
4. **Remove the join** from File1 (Right-click File1 in the table of contents, choose **Joins and Relates/ Remove Join(s)** and remove the File2 join).
5. Then re-merge Files 1 & 2, if so desired.

Comment: I started to do this but got stuck after step3. Before I remerge, I want to delete all of the extra columns that File 2 added to File 1. Oddly, right clicking on the columns to delete leaves me with a grayed out 'delete' instead of a selectable 'delete.'

Comment: Ah - I think you just need to remove the join first. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Andy! I took your advice but slightly modified it so that after the join I ended up selecting by attribute: IS NULL. Then I exported those to a new file and then merged that.